# Proving orthonormality of system by sum of fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, orthonormal

> Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. Prove the system $\{f(t-n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is orthonormal if and only if $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(\omega+2\pi k)|^2\equiv 1$$

I have no clue how to prove both directions. I think that somehow Parsevall's equality has to be applied but I'm not sure how. I'd be glad for any hint.

Comment: Sure. that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: It is either $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ and thus $\hat f$ continuous or the identity is only required to hold almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any advanced wavelet book, this is a fundamental relation for the examination of affine systems.

As you surely know, 
$$
c_n=\int_{\Bbb R}f(t)\overline{f(t-n)}\,dt
=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R} |\hat f(ω)|^2·e^{-inω}\,dω
=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}|\hat f(ω+k·2\pi)|^2·e^{-inω}\,dω
$$
Now the first and last term are about the Fourier series of the $2\pi$ periodic function
$$
g(ω)=|\hat f(ω+k·2\pi)|^2=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}c_ne^{inω}.
$$
Orthonormality is equivalent to $c_n=\delta_{0,n}$ which is equivalent to $g\equiv 1$.

Comment: How you got the first equality $c_n=\int_\mathbb{R}\dots$?

Comment: That was just giving a name to the value of the integral.